# How to secure an API that will be used by mobile apps and the web

Tags: c#, rest, api, security

I'm building a rest API in ASP.Net that will be used by both a web site and a mobile app. The mobile portion of it is done, and it generates an Auth Token that the app hangs on to and sends as a header for every request to the API.

I'm now trying to build out the web app portion of the API and am realizing I may have made a mistake in my security of the API. It seems to me that I cannot simply pass back an Auth Token to the web app that gets sent back and forth as that would leave my API vulnerable to CSRF. I also cannot have the API check for a cookie from mobile, as mobile can't set cookies.

What would be the best way to secure this API so it can be safely used by both a website and a mobile app?

Comment: Unless your auth token is `Authorization: basic`, I don't think you're vulnerable to CSRF.  Take a look at [this post on security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32574/csrf-with-oauth-or-bearer-authorization-headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using headers to pass the auth key back and forth is perfectly fine, so long as the auth key expires in a reasonable amount of time.